# Dont recreate fragment when changing device orientation with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an Activity that contains a ViewPager

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pager_layout);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

Fragments are created in the adapter on the getItem method

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    PageFragment tabFrag = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args =  new Bundle();
    args.putInt("gen", pos);
    tabFrag.setArguments(args);
    return tabFrag;
}
```

My fragment contains an ArrayList that is filled with an asynctask on the OnCreate method of the Fragment.
But if i change the device orientation it will recretae the activity and all the fragments.
How can i conserve my ArrayList and the asynctask if i change the orientation.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in your Activity tag in manifest file